# RunCall structure of Poly/ML

Tags: memory, sml, isabelle, polyml

I'm reading Isabelle's source code while I'm not experienced with programming in general.
I found the use of `RunCall` structure of the Poly/ML basis library (e.g. in [src/Pure/Concurrent/thread_attributes.ML](https://github.com/seL4/isabelle/blob/85506e784adb5140c2a9cc09459f5dbfba489be0/src/Pure/Concurrent/thread_attributes.ML) to manipulate thread flags). I consulted [the documentation of Poly/ML basis library](https://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/Basis.html#RunCall) for `RunCall`, but there is no detailed information for this structure probably because it's clear for well-experienced programmers.

I tried an experiment with `RunCall.loadWord` and `RunCall.loadByte` in REPL (with Intel Core i7): First, I got

```
> val x = "123";
val x = "123": string
> RunCall.loadWord(ref x, 0w0): word;
val it = 0wx3332310000000000000003: word
```

So `loadWord` somehow reads the address given by `ref x`. However, it returns not only the  first 2 byte (= 1 `word`?) `0wx3332` but whole of the data of `x: string`. But

```
> RunCall.loadByte(ref x, 0w0): word;
val it = 0wxC8: word
```

and I cannot extract `0wxC8` from `0wx3332310000000000000003`. Similarly,

```
> val n = 1;
val n = 1: int
> RunCall.loadWord(ref n, 0w0): word;
val it = 0wx1: word
> RunCall.loadByte(ref n, 0w0): word;
val it = 0wx3: word
```

and always `loadByte` returns twice plus one of the result of `loadWord`. (In this experiment, I supposed that `ref x` is something like `&x` of C language.)

So my questions are:

1. Where can I find a manual for `RunCall` of Poly/ML? (Or some document giving a hint for `RunCall`.)
2. In the above example, why `loadWord` returns not only one byte data `0wx33` but `0wx3332310000000000000003`?
3. In the above example, why `loadWord` and `loadByte` returns so different values?

I apologize that my confusion is probably coming from my lack of the basic knowledge on the memory architecture...

---

**Addendum** (this is at least in my environment (Poly/ML 5.9 Release + MacOS X Monterey + Intel Core i7)):
I got a "hypothetical" answer to Q.3 (though I read only some comments in the source of Poly/ML). The points are

A. There are "byte-object" and "word-object" in Poly/ML and the first bit is used as a flag to distinguish these two types of object. The flag `0` is for "byte-object" and the flag `1` is for "word-object". The difference of these objects is the offset: it's 1 byte for "byte-object" and it's 1 word (= 2 byte in my case?) for "word-object".

B. RunCall.loadWord, when applied to `string ref`, it tracks (really???) the referenced address. But RunCall.loadByte does not.

By A., the behavior of the experiment with `1: int` is clear. By B., the exotic value `0wxC8` is just coming from the (first one byte of the) address of the first byte of "123", so it depends on the runtime environment. The appropriate experiment was with

```
> val s = "123";
val s = "123": string
> RunCall.loadWord(ref s,0w0): word;
val it = 0wx3332310000000000000003: word
> RunCall.loadByte(s, 0w0): word;
val it = 0wx3: word
> RunCall.loadByte(s, 0w8): word;
val it = 0wx31: word
> RunCall.loadByte(s, 0w9): word;
val it = 0wx32: word
> RunCall.loadByte(s, 0w10): word;
val it = 0wx33: word
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RunCall` structure contains various very low-level operations and it is only there to allow some libraries to be built on top. It is deliberately undocumented and can change between releases or could even be removed completely.

Comment: Thank you, David. Well, but what I wanted is to know what's happening in such low-level operations. It seems then the source code of Poly/ML is the only "manual"...?

Comment: Also, then it means that Isabelle's source still have codes with some legacy feature of PolyML ...? The implementation of Thread structure of Poly/ML looks similar to the corresponding code in Isabelle's source. I guess then Isabelle's source will be rewritten with the official Thread structure of Poly/ML someday ...?